# Cargar información a un formulario desde la base de datos con un boton

Tags: php, html

Lo que intento es cargar informacion que previamente yo subi a una base de datos con un formulario y despues volver a traer esa informacion con un boton desde otro html que lo que hace es buscar.

```
  <form>
    <input  type="text" id="nombre" required>
    <input  type="date" id="cumpleaños" required>
    <button  type="submit" >Guardar</button>
 </form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi se ve el formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo lleno con los siguientes datos y lo subo a la base de datos hasta alli ningun problema.

```
<form>
  <input  type="text" id="nombre" required>
  <button  type="submit" >Buscar</button>
</form>
<br></br>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Boton</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>Marcos</td>
    <td><button type="button" name="cargar_informacion">Ver informacion</button></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Creo un buscador con php para que busque en la base de datos a la persona y lo mande al html. El php responde creando una tabla con el nombre y un boton que debe dirigir al primer formulario y cargar los datos de esa persona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve el buscador con el resultado de la búsqueda hasta allí todo bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es como configuro este botón para que me mande al formulario.html y cargue la información del cliente. Desde el código del buscador puedo traer el id de la persona de la base de datos y ponerlo en alguna parte de la etiqueta button si es necesario.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se me ocurre son los siguientes pasos:

1. Cambiar tu archivo `formulario.html` por `formulario.php`.
2. Una vez hecho esto, creo una variable donde almacenaré el ID del usuario que encontré.
3. Cambio mi elemento `button` por un elemento `a`. Button no acepta ningún atributo `href`, en cambio elemento `a` si.
4. Dentro de href voy a mandar los valores por el método $_GET para que formulario.php los reciba ahí.
5. Una vez enviándolos, los recibiré en formulario.php con $_GET y con la variable por las que lo mande en el href y ahí es cuando podré realizar la carga de información.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="nombre" required>
  <button type="submit" >Buscar</button>
</form>
<br><br>
<?php
  $ID_USUARIO = 1;
?>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Boton</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>Marcos</td>
    <td><a href="formularip.php?ID_USUARIO=<? echo $ID_USUARIO; ?>" name="cargar_informacion">Ver informacion</a></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```html
<?php
  ///////////////////////////////////////
  // Este es mi archivo formulario.php //
  ///////////////////////////////////////
  $ID_USUARIO = $_GET['ID_USUARIO']
  
   //Hago mi consulta.
  $query = "
    SELECT
      nombre,
      edad,
      nacimiento
    FROM
      usuarios
    WHERE
      id = ${ID_USUARIO}
   ";
   
   //Obtengo el registro de mi consulta
   //Muestro la información en mi HTML
?>
```

Comment: El cambio a la etiqueta "a" es bastante útil pero cambiar a formulario.php esta fuera de la solución. Eso que haces con ?? en la etiqueta "a" podria funcionar con href="formularip.html?34?"  (34 es el id de la persona en la base de datos) con un script podria tomar ese numero y cargar los datos.  Gracias por tu aportación.

Comment: No puede funcionar de esa manera la etiqueta a, JAMÁS. Para eso necesitas que tu archivo 'formulario' sea en PHP. ¿Por que está fuera de solución cambiar el formulario de HTML a PHP?